# How to disable textbox dropdown suggestions on certain websites?

Tags: textbox, autohotkey, dropdown

I am trying to make my job easier by creating simple AHK scrips to auto-fill certain forms online.
Im not really good at explaining, but hopefully someone will understand what Im saying.
 The problem is that this website has certain textboxes with dropdown auto-suggestions turned on, and it has a delay when selecting those textboxes. 
I assume when selecting textbox it is pulling data from some database which is causing delay.
 
**Now my question is. Is it possible to turn off dropdown menu on websites or even in entire browser if necessary?** 
I really want to my script to tab-in, wright down whats needed, tab-out without delay.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete dropdown lists are just JS scripts. So there is no way, I think, to disable them by clicking checkbox in browser settings.

First, try to disable JS completely.

Also, if only few sites are involved, you could try to find out what JS libraries are used and disable them in browser JS console.

Comment: So I tried disabling JS, but it turns out page cannot open without it. I dont think there is a solution...

Comment: @Roki_09 agree, in all probabilitiy, there is no simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to do this via keypresses or via COM?

I imagine that via keypresses you could not avoid focusing the elements and triggering the information lookup.

AutoHotkey can interact with webpages on Internet Explorer using COM (Component Object Model).
COM can launch/latch onto an IE instance, detect if the page is loading/has loaded, navigate to a particular url, and set the text of web elements,
quite possibly without triggering the drop-down lists. I haven't tested if COM can disable elements, it's possible.
Also, Acc.ahk may be able to set the text of elements.